# Bash: All commands not found

Tags: bash, macos, shell, command-line, terminal

I'm running Mac OSX 10.12.5. No matter what commands I type into the Terminal, all return `-bash: -c: command not found` or `-bash: -a: command not found` or whatever command I'm trying to run. I am extremely new to command-line coding, and I don't even know where to start looking, so forgive me if this question is a duplicate--I literally have no idea how to even begin to troubleshoot this. I've perused some other answers here, but they're all very specific to the circumstance. Can someone point me in the right direction on this?

Comment: Please be more specific: WHAT are you trying to type in? Does `ls` work? `echo`?

Comment: The first command I tried was `-c 'import sys; print(sys.executable)'`. I just typed in `echo` and nothing but a blank space appeared. `echo $PROMPT_COMMAND` produced `update_terminal_cwd`. I just tried `alias`, and that produced `alias activate_canopy='source '\''/Users/me/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate'\'''`.

Comment: This: `-c 'import sys; print(sys.executable)'` looks like Python. You need to type python before that: `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.executable)'`

Comment: That produces the following error: `dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Python
  Referenced from: /Users/me/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6`

Comment: What if you just type `python`?

Comment: Same error: `dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Python
  Referenced from: /Users/me/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6`

Comment: That instance of Python is corrupted I think. How did it get installed?

Comment: I installed Python 3.5 via Enthought Canopy 2.1.2.3530. Is that Python folder above is being inappropriately called for every command? (By the way, it would make sense that it is corrupted--even though Canopy works fine, Rodeo only produces "Unable to execute" errors no matter the code that is typed in. IPython doesn't even work there.)

Comment: @Yehuda No, you have two different problems here: first, the commands that're giving you the "command not found" errors are not valid shell commands (i.e. those errors *should* occur when you type them in). They look like they're supposed to be options to the `python` command. The second (completely unrelated) problem is that there's something wrong with how Python is installed and/or set up on your system, so when you actually do invoke it, you get dyld errors.

Comment: How would I go about correcting the Python installation? I've tried to uninstall and reinstall Canopy before, including deleting the plist, but it doesn't seem to help. These issues seem to have come about as a result of my switch from Canopy 1.7.4 with Python 2.7 to Canopy 2.1.2 with Python 3.5. Would that be related?